# how to authenticate in a symfony project when i login from another one

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, session-cookies

i have 2 symfony projects project 1 and project 2 and want to authenticate in both using the login form in project 1. both projects have the same database my projects hostnames are for example project1.test and project2.test they are not in the same domain

i tried sharing session in the database and using PDOsession handler

```
session:
handler_id: Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Storage\\Handler\\PdoSessionHandler
save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions'
cookie_secure: auto
cookie_samesite: lax
```

but i could not find a way to get that session in the second project i'm not sure how i can do that

Comment: I'm not sure that is secure to share a session between multi domain. May be the solution is that the 2 project use the same identity provider with a protocol like openid connect or SAML. Then if the user is authenticated on the provider, if he goes to the first projet, he will be automatically authenticated in ; same thing if he goes to the second.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can handle that if applications run on subdomains otherwise you probabaly need some kind of SSO mechanism with auth provider. Please check for example https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/single-sign-on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was possible to use subdomaines so i ended up sharing session in mysql for both projects and configure the same cookie_domaine and trusted domaines on both projects in framwork.yaml

```
session:
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    cookie_secure: auto
    name: shared_session
    cookie_domain: '.example.com'
    cookie_lifetime: 0 
    gc_maxlifetime: 86400 # Set the desired TTL in seconds
    gc_probability: 1 
trusted_hosts: ['product.example.com', 'cart.example.com']
```

setting cookie_lifetime to 0 allows you to use gc_maxlifetime instead
i hope this is helpful to someone <3